# IRC Bot commands

Tags: c#, interface

I have created a very simple IRC bot for Twitch.tv in C#. Right now I only have commands to PING and other twitch messages. I am using state pattern to handle the different commands. The (furture) problem arrives when creating commands. I have made a CommandProvider class that creates the different commands like this:

```
public interface ICommandProvider
{
    Dictionary<string, ICommandState> CommandList { get; set; }
}

public class CommandProvider : ICommandProvider
{
    public CommandProvider(IIRC irc)
    {
        CommandList = new Dictionary<string, ICommandState>();
        CommandList.Add("PING",new PingCommand() {Irc = irc});
        CommandList.Add("376",new Command376() { Irc = irc });
        CommandList.Add("366",new Command366() { Irc = irc });
    }
    public Dictionary<string, ICommandState> CommandList { get; set; } 
}
```

Every command is derived from `ICommandState` that looks like this:

```
public interface ICommandState
{
    IIRC Irc { get; set; }
    void Execute(object para = null);
}
```

The problem is I want to add a lot of commands, some might use a pointsystem class, another would use a queuesystem and yet another command would maybe use IRC and the pointsystem class. There will properly be more classes that are used by different commands when im done, but I am afraid my ICommandState will break the interface segregation principle ? As some commands might not need to know about all the different classes.

One solution I thought about was to make the IRC class,Pointsystem class and so on, static so every command could access them when they needed them but my intuition tells me this is wrong(if it is why?)

I hope someone can come with a smart solution to my problem

Comment: It may help you to literally draw out a flow diagram of what happens when a command comes in, how it is handled, etc. That flow should work for EVERY command regardless of its classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# supports inheriting from multiple interfaces so you have this segregation at a 2nd level, for extra interfaces these classes implement to do specific things

However  I'd derive all those interfaces from a common one and use single inheritance

Btw, checkout IoC (Inversion of Control) containers and MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework), included in recent .NET versions

Comment: Ah thank you took some time before I got what you ment! Thanks a lot